# Как сжать изображение и отправить определенный размер на клиент Андроид и Айос?

Tags: python, изображения, веб-сервер, flask

Пытался разными способами сжать изображение под определенный размер, используя flask-resize, flask-images. Загружаю изображение через

```
def allowed_file(filename):
return '.' in filename and \
       filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

def upload_file(file):
if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return filename
else:
    return -1)
```

Изображения хранятся в папке. Отправляю файл через

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                           filename)
```

Comment: так что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Сжатие картинки. Отправлять большое изображение - это очень большой удар по трафику.

Comment: не вижу в вашем коде, где вы пытаетесь сжать изображение

Comment: да, это просто загрузка и отправка. А я спрашиваю, как именно сжать файл. Flask-resize и Flask-Image это кажется для работы с шаблонами

Comment: [здесь](https://flask-resize.readthedocs.org/api.html#flask_resize.create_placeholder_img) описаны методы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://flask-resize.readthedocs.org/api.html#flask_resize.create_placeholder_img
Библиотека PIL для сжатия и изменения изображения